# jQuery Selector to Return All Elements Hidden By an Element Without a Particular Class

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to write a single selector to query for all elements which have a hidden parent where the hidden parent doesn't have a specific class.

For example given the HTML below, it would only select Field2 as it's parent is hidden and the parent element that hides it does not have the "tab" class.

```
<div class="tab" style="display: none;">
    <div>
        <input name="Field1" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input name="Field2" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab" style="display: none;">
    <div>
        <input name="Field3" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <div>
        <input name="Field4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what u r looking for?

```
$("div:not(.tab) > *:hidden")
```

or

```
$("div:hidden:not(.tab) > *:hidden")
```

---- edit ----
You can do like this

```
$("div[style='display: none;']:not(.tab) > *")
```

but it is not really a good approach. I would rather change those style='display: none;' to a css class, then run like this; and I tested here http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/KaaYc/

```
$("div.noShow:not(.tab) > *")
```

Comment: This looks promising however it also returns Field1 and Field3. I also need to return the hidden fields that are not within a tab.

Comment: this happens because :hidden selector does check if it is visible or not. so, if parent is not visible :hidden matches. I assume you are looking for div with style='display:none'. In that case :hidden does not match your requirement.

Comment: Thanks again. This correctly returned the right nodes but if I hide the node using jQuery then it won't have the .noShow class and the element won't be selected.

Comment: You can hide JQuery node not by JQuery.hide(), but JQuery.addClass("noShow"). To show, JQuery.addClass("noShow"). By doing so, you don't need to set style directly to the element.

Comment: Thanks I guess this will have to do. Another option I was considering was to hide tab by make it absolute positioned. That way I can simply retrieve the hidden elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':hidden:has(*)').filter(function(){
    return !this.class;
}).find('*').dojQueryFuncHere();
```

Though I must say it's not the best thing to do, query for "something" - `*`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('div:not(.tab):hidden input');
```

Comment: Thanks but this returned Field 1, 3 and I need it to only return Field2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input").filter(function() { 
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    return parent.css("display") == "none" && parent.not(".tab");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a parent is hidden, its descendants are also considered hidden so the `:hidden` selector will not do exactly what you need.  The only way is to actually check the `style` attribute in this case.

```
$("[style*='display: none']:not(.tab) >");
```

This selects all elements with `style="display: none"` (the space between `:` and `none` is required, but you could also write another selector that does not require it, and that do not have the `.tab` class.

*This will obviously not work if the parent can be hidden by something other than `style` such as a class.  In that case there's not a whole lot you can do unless you want to parse the stylesheet and inspect each individual parent and its classes.*

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zXmXL/1/

Contrats with `$("body :hidden:not(.tab) >")`.  The `body` is used because all `<head>` is `:hidden`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zXmXL/3/